# Removing oauth authorization on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have authorize an application through oauth on my Heroku account. And now I want to remove this authorization. But I am not able to find where or how I can remove this authorization.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should let you manage your oauth tokens from the command line. When it is made public
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-oauth

For now send a support request to heroku and we will remove the auth for you.

Comment: are you linking to a private repo?

Comment: Oops... I will see if i can get it made public.

Comment: @JohnBeynon the CLI plugin is public now.